# Posterior Distribution using Jeffreys prior

Tags: self-study, bayesian, jeffreys-prior

I'm trying to show that if $X_1, \cdots, X_n \stackrel{iid}{\sim} N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ with unknown $\mu$, $\sigma$ and the prior $\pi(\mu, \sigma^2) \propto 1/\sigma^2$ then the posterior distribution of $\mu$ is given by $$\frac{\sqrt{n} (\mu - \bar{x})}{s_{n-1}} \sim t_{n-1} $$
where $\bar{x} = \frac{1}{n} \sum x_i$ is the sample mean and $s_{n-1} = \frac{1}{n-1} \sum (x_i - \bar{x})^2$ is the sample variance. I know that $\sum (x_i - \bar{x})^2 \sim \chi^2_{n-1}$ by a standard result. So to show that $$\frac{\sqrt{n} (\mu - \bar{x})}{s_{n-1}} \sim t_{n-1} ,$$
I just need the numerator to be $N(0, 1)$ but I'm not too sure how. I note that $$\pi(\mu, \sigma^2|\mathbf{x}) \propto (\sigma^2)^{-(1 + n/2)} \text{exp} \left( \frac{-1}{2\sigma^2} \sum (x_i - \mu)^2 \right) $$
but I got stuck here. Anyone can give me suggestions from here?

Comment: "Jeffreys", not "Jeffrey", after Sir Harold Jeffreys.

Comment: A first step is rewriting the sum in the exponent as 
\begin{align}
\sum(x_i-\mu)^2&=n\mu^2-2\mu\sum x_i+\sum x_i^2
\\&=n(\mu-\bar x)^2-n\bar x^2+\sum x_i^2
\\&=n(\mu-\bar x)^2+\sum(x_i-\bar x)^2
\end{align}
by completing the square in $\mu$.  It is then immediate
 that the posterior of $\mu$ conditional on $\sigma$ is normal and that marginal posterior of $\sigma^2$ is inverse gamma.

Comment: Special case of https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/178199/7224